# search for values after strings-multiple columns

Tags: linux, bash

I have this file (output.txt):

```
    name:some name^M
    ^M
    count:1^M
    ^M
    region:some_region
    name:some name^M
    ^M
    count:2^M
    ^M
    region:some_region^M
    ^M
    name:some name^M
    ^M
    count:1^M
    ^M
    region:some_region^M
    ^M
 
Testing Powershell scripts execustions from Rundeck server against Windows server
```

How to get only values after name,count and region

desired output:

```
some name 1 some region
some name 2 some region
some name 1 some region
```

with   `grep -E 'name|count|region' output.txt | sed 's/^.*: //'`

i got

```
some name
1
some_region
some name
2
some_region
some name
1
some_region
```

How to generate multiple columns ?

Comment: [*Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/355310) -- No. Cross-site duplicate [on Unix & Linux SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/434281/108618).

Comment: Please read the linked meta question ^^^ and act accordingly: delete one of the two cross-site duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

One possible answer using awk:

```
cat input | awk '/name: /{name=substr($0,7)} /count: /{cnt=substr($0,8)} /region:/{print name" "cnt" "substr($0,9)}'
```

Comment: nope, only some region colum is shown

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '/^(name|count|region):/{
         sep = (/^region/? ORS : OFS);
         gsub(/^[^:]+:[[:space:]]*|[[:space:]]*$/, "");
         printf "%s%s", $0, sep 
     }' file.txt
```

Thanks to @RomanPerekhrest